# FMU export from Dymola - When are the code export options required?

Tags: dymola, fmi

The goal is to export an FMU to be run on a target machine without a Dymola license. Do I always need a specific license?

Without enabling the code export options in the license setup, all FMU types (`me`, `cs`, `all`, `csSolver`) seem to require a Dymola installation on the target machine.

Somehow I had it different in mind. Also, from the Dymola Manual 2B, 1.1.2 Exporting FMUs from Dymola I understand that Binary Model Export license is only required when trying to export an FMU of type `csSolver`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To export an FMU that does not require a Dymola license key on the target computer, you always need one of the code export options. You pay for the capability, not for the embedded solver.